# Excel Macro Loop to concatenate columns from proceeding rows into a column in row above

Tags: excel, vba

`I have an excel file created by a data file where a memo field is breaking into other rows.  I need to take the proceeding rows columns and concatenate them to the first row's column memo field.  I need a macro that will go through the file concatenate these proceeding row columns to the first row column and delete the proceeding rows.

Example:(not able to attach an image because I am a new user)

ColumnA      Column B   Column C          Column D

Row ID       Date       ID Number         Description

```
2        1/21/2010  2010000135        Music too loud in room. 
         Additionally, you have a pending Notice of Charge.
4        1/21/2010  2010000182        Blasting music in your room. 
         Finding notes 
         I explained discplinary process
```

What I need it to look like:

```
2        1/21/2010  2010000135        Music too loud in room. Additionally, you have a pending Notice of Charge.
4        1/21/2010  2010000182        Blasting music in your room. Finding notes I explained discplinary process
```

The memo description line breaks up in various number of rows, though I can distingquish the rows where the memo line breaks up because the Row ID is blank.  How can I concatenate column B of multiple rows to column E (Description) throughout the spreadsheet and delete the rows once they have been concatenated into the description field in a macro until it reaches end of file?

Comment: how much data are you talking about? can you expand your example to show more than just 1 line? i think it's important to see a bigger picture to answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming an index in 1st column, a date in 2nd column and a text in 3rd column which overflows to 2nd column in next line (meaning that column 1 in break text lines are empty) ...

```
Sub Beautify()
Dim R As Range, Idx As Long

    Set R = Selection
    Idx = 1

    Do While Idx < R.Rows.Count                           ' count dynamically changes as we delete rows
        If R(Idx + 1, 1) = "" Then                        ' found a break line looking 1 down
            R(Idx, 3) = R(Idx, 3) & " " & R(Idx + 1, 2)   ' append to current
            R(Idx + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete                ' delete following but do not count up Idx
        Else
            Idx = Idx + 1                                 ' this one is clean, advance
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

select your full list and run the macro ....

```
before Beautify()
=================
1   01.01.2010  Text 1
2   01.10.2010  Text 1
    Text 2  
3   01.10.2010  Text 1
    Text 2  
    Text 3  
4   01.01.2010  Text 1
5   01.10.2010  Text 1
    Text 2  

after Beautify()
=================
1   01.01.2010  Text 1
2   01.10.2010  Text 1 Text 2
3   01.10.2010  Text 1 Text 2 Text 3
4   01.01.2010  Text 1
5   01.10.2010  Text 1 Text 2
```

Comment: MikeD - Thank you!  I'm glad you could understand what I needed.  It works wonderfully.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: So once you finalized your solution I would be glad if you "accept" my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The row Id couldn't be blank. The rows have been splitted either by

```
1) <Alt>+<enter> at the end of each line or 

2) your columns are too narrow.
```

[For getting rid of the Alt+Enter](http://thedailyreviewer.com/office/view/replace-altenter-from-multiple-text-cell-112449526):

```
Select the range, press Ctrl+H, hold down the ALT key and
type in "0010" (no quotes) on your numeric keypad. Press
TAB and in the "Replace With" type a space. 
Press "Replace All".
```

Comment: I was having a problem pasting the spreadsheet.  So I tried to type in the example.  Each section separated by spaces are a separate column.  (Columns A through H).  Importing the text file split column H, where the text showed up in column B (sometimes over more than one row).

Comment: @user518937 From where are you tring to paste the spreadsheet? Can you post a screen capture?

Comment: Column A is row id.  I manipulated the file so that row id would be blank for the rows with the split text that I would like to concatenate to column H.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @user518937 Not for me :( Can you post a screen capture?  From where are you tring to paste the spreadsheet?

Comment: @user518937  Please note I've edited the instructions For getting rid of the Alt+Enter:

Comment: Belisarius - The <Ctrl H> isn't working.  It's not an Alt+Enter.  It happened when exporting a memo field for SQL Server into a text file.  When exporting the file into Excel, it breaks the line into COLUMN B in the next row.  The line can be broken into 1 or 5 extra rows with the text in column B, which I need to concatenate to column H.

Comment: I did a <CTRL> <ALT> Print Screen and then tried to paste it.  But it wouldn't paste.  Do you know a better way to paste it?  Thanks.

Comment: @user518937 Edit your question instead of posting a coment . While editing an image icon on top of the edit window appears (along with other icons). Click on it for uploading an image. Press here to edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4268170/edit or press the **edit** sign below your question

Comment: I wasn't able to attach an image file, because I am a new user.  So, I tried to clarify the detail in the question.  I hope this clarifies things and will help someone to assist me.  Thank you, belisarius for trying to assist.

Comment: @user518937 Don't you have your original sheet, with the "row numbers missing"?

Comment: I do have my original sheet.  But I am not able to attach the image file.  This software will not let me because it says I am a new user and am unable to attach image files.  Each new line is a new row number with the way I typed in the text.

Comment: @user518937 OK, please try ON THAT SHEET the recipe from this answer. Select all the sheet as target